# Javascript change id from form input

Tags: javascript

I am working on a new project and I ran into one issue

I want to have a form where the user can enter their username so a 3d image is generated.
The code for the image generator is:

```
<span class="mc-skin" data-minecraft-username="UsernameHere"></span>
```

and what I need is a input field that changed the data-minecraft-username to the input of the form.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: question is not clear, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: You need to be able to reference the span, so maybe give it an ID. Then use `document.getElementById('spanID').setAttribute('data-minecraft-username', newValue)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would give the span the ID "Skin" would the code for the input be: `<script>document.getElementById('Skin').setAttribute('data-minecraft-username', newValue) </script>
          
               <input id="Skin" type="text" value="Input Value"/>
 



<span id="Skin" class="mc-skin" data-minecraft-username="UsernameHere"></span>
`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var user="Zane";

document.getElementsByClassName("mc-skin")[0].setAttribute('data-minecraft-username',user);
```

But it will be better if you will use id for that particular span and set it like this:
add `id="spanId"` then use

```
document.getElementById('spanId').setAttribute('data-minecraft-username', user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5

Example:

```
variable.setAttribute('data-minecraft-username','randomUserName');
```

variable beeing your span element

More reference here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most robust way to deal with `data-*` attributes is to use *setAttribute* and *getAttribute*. If the span has an id of *Skin*, then you might use:

```
var span = document.getElementById('Skin');
span.setAttribute('data-minecraft-username', newValue);
```

You can also use the [*element.dataset*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) property:

```
span.dataset['minecraft-username'] = newValue;
```

Which will add a *data-minecraft-unsername* attribute with a value of whatever is in *newValue*. However, support may be lacking in older browsers (see [*MDN HTMLElement.dataset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset), which indicates fairly recent browsers such as IE 11, Safari 6, etc. are  required).

Also see [*MDN Using data attributes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

To use the above script in a document, you might do something like:

```
<script>
function setDataAttribute(elID, attName, value) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elID);
  if (el) {
    el.setAttribute('data-' + attName, value);
  }
}

function setContent(elID, value) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elID);
  if (el) {
    el.innerHTML = value;
  }
}

</script>


<span id="Skin"></span>
<br>
<input type="text" onblur="
  setDataAttribute('Skin', 'minecraft-username', this.value);
  setContent('Skin', this.value);
">
```